# why am i getting "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a beginner in javascript, i am trying made a input tag with the type number. and links the javascript file with my html file. this is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/js/function-plot.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="exerciseJavascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="hello" type="number" value=2 oninput="putInConsole();">
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is my javascript

```
var x = document.querySelector("#hello").value;

    function putInConsole(){
        console.log(x);
    }
```

and the error shown in the console is
'''

```
0: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference
exerciseJavascript.js (1,1)
```

I dont know why the value is undefined. please help me with it

Comment: I guess script is getting downloaded before page load. Please try to execute script on documentLoaded event.

Comment: Move `var x = document.querySelector("#hello").value;` INSIDE

 `function putInConsole(){
        console.log(x);
    }`

Comment: @JackOfAshes-MohitGawande  thank you for your help now my javascript is now working fine. thank you once again.